# Products just redirect to search results page

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, product-urls

All of my products are now redirecting to catalog search.

i.e.

```
/bonfire-firma-3-in-1-stretch-mens-snowboard-jacket-2019.html
```

goes to

```
/catalogsearch/result/?q=bonfire-firma-3-in-1-stretch-mens-snowboard-jacket-2019
```

What can I do to fix this ?

I have these modules installed:

```
Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout
Amasty_Base
Amasty_Blog
Amasty_CrossLinks
Amasty_CustomerAttributes
Amasty_Feed
Amasty_Label
Amasty_Meta
Amasty_Scroll
Amasty_SeoHtmlSitemap
Amasty_SeoRichData
Amasty_SeoSingleUrl
Amasty_SeoToolKit
Amasty_Shopby
Amasty_ShopbyBase
Amasty_ShopbyBrand
Amasty_ShopbyPage
Amasty_ShopbySeo
Amasty_Sorting
Amasty_XmlSitemap
Amasty_Xsearch
Amazon_Core
Amazon_Login
Amazon_Payment
Anowave_Ec
Anowave_Package
Auctane_Api
Dotdigitalgroup_Email
Iazel_RegenProductUrl
Klarna_Core
Klarna_Kp
Klarna_Ordermanagement
Kodal_AmastyBrandLink
Kodal_AmastyLabelMod
Kodal_AmastyShopByMod
Kodal_CheckoutMod
Kodal_CompareMod
Kodal_Contact
Kodal_CustomImage
Kodal_GetCustomVariable
Kodal_ProductIcons
Kodal_QuickFeaturedProducts
Kodal_ShippingCountdown
Kodal_ShopbyBrand
Kodal_Sizeify
Kodal_StockOptions
Kodal_TermsConditionsPage
Kodal_UbMegamenuMod
Kodal_WishlistMod
Magento_AdminNotification
Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport
Magento_Analytics
Magento_Authorization
Magento_Authorizenet
Magento_Backend
Magento_Backup
Magento_Braintree
Magento_Bundle
Magento_BundleImportExport
Magento_CacheInvalidate
Magento_Captcha
Magento_Catalog
Magento_CatalogAnalytics
Magento_CatalogImportExport
Magento_CatalogInventory
Magento_CatalogRule
Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable
Magento_CatalogSearch
Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite
Magento_CatalogWidget
Magento_Checkout
Magento_CheckoutAgreements
Magento_Cms
Magento_CmsUrlRewrite
Magento_Config
Magento_ConfigurableImportExport
Magento_ConfigurableProduct
Magento_ConfigurableProductSales
Magento_Contact
Magento_Cookie
Magento_Cron
Magento_CurrencySymbol
Magento_Customer
Magento_CustomerAnalytics
Magento_CustomerImportExport
Magento_Deploy
Magento_Developer
Magento_Dhl
Magento_Directory
Magento_Downloadable
Magento_DownloadableImportExport
Magento_Eav
Magento_Email
Magento_EncryptionKey
Magento_Fedex
Magento_GiftMessage
Magento_GoogleAdwords
Magento_GoogleAnalytics
Magento_GoogleOptimizer
Magento_GroupedImportExport
Magento_GroupedProduct
Magento_ImportExport
Magento_Indexer
Magento_InstantPurchase
Magento_Integration
Magento_LayeredNavigation
Magento_Marketplace
Magento_MediaStorage
Magento_Msrp
Magento_Multishipping
Magento_NewRelicReporting
Magento_Newsletter
Magento_OfflinePayments
Magento_OfflineShipping
Magento_PageCache
Magento_Payment
Magento_Paypal
Magento_Persistent
Magento_ProductAlert
Magento_ProductVideo
Magento_Quote
Magento_QuoteAnalytics
Magento_ReleaseNotification
Magento_Reports
Magento_RequireJs
Magento_Review
Magento_ReviewAnalytics
Magento_Robots
Magento_Rss
Magento_Rule
Magento_Sales
Magento_SalesAnalytics
Magento_SalesInventory
Magento_SalesRule
Magento_SalesSequence
Magento_SampleData
Magento_Search
Magento_Security
Magento_SendFriend
Magento_Shipping
Magento_Signifyd
Magento_Sitemap
Magento_Store
Magento_Swagger
Magento_SwaggerWebapi
Magento_Swatches
Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation
Magento_Tax
Magento_TaxImportExport
Magento_Theme
Magento_Translation
Magento_Ui
Magento_Ups
Magento_UrlRewrite
Magento_User
Magento_Usps
Magento_Variable
Magento_Vault
Magento_Version
Magento_Webapi
Magento_WebapiSecurity
Magento_Weee
Magento_Widget
Magento_Wishlist
Magento_WishlistAnalytics
Mageplaza_ProductFeed
Magestore_Appadmin
Magestore_Payment
Magestore_Webpos
Magestore_WebposAuthorizenet
Magestore_WebposBambora
Magestore_WebposIntegration
Magestore_WebposPaynl
Magestore_WebposPaypal
Magestore_WebposStripe
Magestore_WebposTyro
MGS_Ajaxscroll
MGS_Core
MSP_Common
MSP_DevTools
Temando_Shipping
Ubertheme_UbMegaMenu
Vertex_Tax
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your custom module doing this

Comment: yes it could be, but I have many installed, but which one ?

Comment: Please share of extension which you have use?

Comment: I have added a list of all modules.

Comment: Could it be this: main.WARNING: Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '471' how do i Fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be related to product catalog url keys. For me, I installed this module https://packagist.org/packages/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites. There is a list of commands `php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=product` worked for me. It basically regenerates the url keys.

Comment: yes this is good solution but its not usefull when 2 or more product have same name. because it regenerate the same url key.